# UISlider change values by touching its track

Tags: ios7

I am beginner in ios and I have done basic functionality with UISlider , changing its value on dragging thumb. But now in my app I want to move the thumb of slider gradually in same direction where I am touching slider's track without dragging the thumb of slider. Thumb must reach to exact touched position on the track in 2 or more steps.
I know it requires involvement of UITouch but unable to understand HOW?

Answer (score 0):

You need to subclass UISlider to add this functionality. After subclassing, you need to implement `touchesBegan` and `touchedMoved` in your subclass. Well, here how i did

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGFloat maxX = CGRectGetMaxX(self.frame);
    CGFloat minX = CGRectGetMinX(self.frame);
    int value =  (maxX - minX) /(self.maximumValue - self.minimumValue);
    [self setValue:([touch locationInView:self].x - minX) / value  animated:YES];
    [self beginTrackingWithTouch:touch withEvent:event];
}
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [self continueTrackingWithTouch:[touches anyObject] withEvent:event];
}
```

You need more work to stabilise a little bit more when user first tap, but i hope you get the idea.